# Apple App Guidelines -- Private APIs?

Tags: api, private

From what I've read, Apple rejects apps using Private APIS. What determines a private API? I am currently using the NinevehGL engine which is open for commercial use, does it count as a private API?

Comment: I apologize for posting the question, I found the answer. A private API refers to any undocumented methodology within Apple's own API. Apple restricts this because if your app relies on calling an undocumented method within Apple's core framework, and then that undocumented method is modified or dropped all together in the next OS update, your app will break and render itself useless. 

Using outside APIs like the NinevehGL engine Im using is perfectly fine, assuming NinevehGL itself isn't using any private APIs.

Im a new user so I cant answer yet, so the comment will have to suffice.

Comment: Could you post this as an **answer** to your question and accept it when time allows. It's okay to answer your own questions here on SO :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the answer.

A private API refers to any undocumented methodology within Apple's own API. Apple restricts this because if your app relies on calling an undocumented method within Apple's core framework, and then that undocumented method is modified or dropped all together in the next OS update, your app will break and render itself useless.

Using outside APIs like the NinevehGL engine Im using is perfectly fine, assuming NinevehGL itself isn't using any private APIs.

Comment: +1 For coming back and answering. This helps others who may find your question. Don't forget to mark it as the answer (when time allows) by clicking the tick mark against this answer.